# how to get javascript api scope inside an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, fotorama

Working with fotorama, I have a question regarding scope.. I'm able to call the api after the fotorama html instance is loaded (api call must be placed below the html fotorama div to work as shown below) but when I put that api call into an onclick function, console gives the error that fotorama is not a function. Here's the code that works (replaces the images in the fotorama div) -

```
<div class="fotorama">
    <img src="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
    <img src="img3.jpg">
    <img src="img4.jpg">
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
    var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();       

    // 2. Get the API object.
    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

    fotorama.load([
            {img: 'img1.jpg', thumb: '1_thumb.jpg'},
            {img: 'img1.jpg', thumb: '2_thumb.jpg'},
            {img: 'img1.jpg', thumb: '3_thumb.jpg'}
            ]);             

    // 3. Inspect it in console.
    console.log(fotorama);

</script>
```

And here is what I'm trying to get to work, the same fotorama api call but in an onclick function-

```
  $( ".button" ).click(function() { 

    // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
    var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();       

    // 2. Get the API object.
    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

    fotorama.load([
            {img: 'img1.jpg', thumb: '1_thumb.jpg'},
            {img: 'img1.jpg', thumb: '2_thumb.jpg'},
            {img: 'img1.jpg', thumb: '3_thumb.jpg'}
            ]);             

    // 3. Inspect it in console.
    console.log(fotorama);
});
```

I assume this is an issue of scope. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Probably not your actual issue... But one issue I foresee with this idea is the fotorama being instantiated at each click... Better use `$( ".button" ).one("click", function() {` where `.one()` will trigger only once. ;)

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette but issue persists. Wouldn't fotorama already be instantiated at that once already?

Comment: I don't get your question. The instantiation occurs when you call `$(element).fotorama();`. If you call it twice or more on the same element, like any plugin... Problems are to be expected.

Comment: Now check if `fotorama.js` is loaded. I don't see any difference instantiating on load or after, on event.

Answer (score 0):

What am I doing that is different from what you are doing?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- 1. Link to jQuery (1.8 or later), -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- 33 KB -->

    <!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
    <link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script> <!-- 16 KB -->

  </head>
<body>
  <div class="fotorama">
  </div>

  <button class="button">hit me</button>

  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    $( ".button" ).click(function() { 

      // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
      var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();       

      // 2. Get the API object.
      var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

      fotorama.load([
              {img: 'http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg'}
              ]);             

      // 3. Inspect it in console.
      console.log(fotorama);
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could try putting your onclick initialisation in the document ready block :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- 1. Link to jQuery (1.8 or later), -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- 33 KB -->

    <!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
    <link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script> <!-- 16 KB -->

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".button" ).click(function() { 

          // 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
          var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();       

          // 2. Get the API object.
          var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

          fotorama.load([
                  {img: 'http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg'}
                  ]);             

          // 3. Inspect it in console.
          console.log(fotorama);
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="fotorama">
  </div>

  <button class="button">hit me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a full example file exhibiting the problem?

Comment: Thanks @the4thamgo_uk your example works, but something else must be interfering on my site. I got it to work but I don't understand why. Posted the answer here.

Comment: The link is not available in your comment. Can you post again or update the question with your code.

Comment: Posted the solution as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize fotorama outside of the button click function.

```
// 1. Initialize fotorama manually.
var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();

 $( ".button" ).click(function() {
```